# Controls not created programatically using PerformClick event

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using `Windows Forms`, I create button programmatically as:

```
var button = new Button
{
    Name = "btnJob",
    Text = "test",
};

button.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
button.Click += OnProjectButtonClick;
```

As you can see I use `Click` event, so in my Click event I create another controls inside a panel like:

```
private void OnProjectButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewContactPanel = new TableLayoutPanel
    {
        AutoSize = true,
        Visible = false
    };

    var lblContactType = new Label
    {
        Name = "lblContactType",
        Text = "Type",
        AutoSize = true,
        Margin = new Padding(15, 10, 0, 0),
    };

    NewContactPanel.Controls.Add(lblContactType, 0, 0);

    CboContactType = new ComboBox
    {
        Name = "cboContactType",
        Width = 130,
        Margin = new Padding(3, 7, 0, 0),
        DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList,
    };

    NewContactPanel.Controls.Add(CboContactType, 1, 0);

    var lblNewContactName = new Label
    {
        Name = "lblNewContactName",
        Text = "Name *",
        AutoSize = true,
        Margin = new Padding(15, 10, 0, 0),
    };

    NewContactPanel.Controls.Add(lblNewContactName, 2, 0);
}
```

It works correctly without problems, but now I want to execute this click event programmatically so I do something like:

```
var firstPanel = tlpJobs.Controls.OfType<TableLayoutPanel>().FirstOrDefault();
var firstButton = firstPanel.Controls.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault();
firstButton.PerformClick();
```

So I used `PreformClick();` event. When I debug, it fire event correctly, the button is clicked correctly too, but controls are not created in my panel. What am I doing wrong? if I click with a mouse at the same button panel is created correctly!, why is not working with PerformClick();? Any ideas?

Comment: You probably should explain what you believe happens on ` NewContactPanel = new TableLayoutPanel{}` line. (Clearly you know how to add controls properly based on the rest of the code)

Comment: So, the Button should be child the TableLayoutPanel that the Button.Click itself is creating? Have you though about the *mechanics* of this procedure and its consequences for a moment? What's the Button.Click for after you have created the TableLayoutPanel? And the actions caused by new Buttons controls? Also, the TableLayoutPanel itself is never added to an existing Parent container Controls collection.Anyway, you don't need PerformClick(), you need to move the code tha'ts inside `OnProjectButtonClick` to a method, so you can call this method from anywhere else, if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set `Button.Parent` property

`Control.Parent` Property

Gets or sets the parent container of the control.